# I'm trying to make a program that mashes two words together, but it just stops working when I add a function

Tags: javascript, function

This is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<span id="demo"></span>
<span>-</span>
<span id="demo2"></span>
<script>
var words = ["Word", "Another Word", "One last word"];
var wordsLast = ["Suffix", "more", "and more"]
function textMasher() = {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = neem[Math.round(Math.random()*2)];
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = neemLast[Math.round(Math.random()*2)];
}

</script>
<button type = "button" onclick =  textMasher()>sample text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If i just remove the function, it runs without error.
I've tried making the function include the list declarations, and put the button above and below the script tags.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run the code as you posted here? If so what are they?

Comment: {
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '='",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 19,
  "colno": 23
}

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the error message and indicate what line causes the error. Also, does this error occur when you load the page or when you click the button.

Answer (score 2):

You have an = sign after the function name. So here is the correct code:

```
function textMasher() {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = words[Math.round(Math.random()*2)];
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = wordsLast[Math.round(Math.random()*2)];
}
```

Comment: oh. i thought it would be much harder than that. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
function textMasher() = {
```

The `=` is not needed here. Change it to

```
function textMasher() {
```

Notice that the error message tells you the problem is on line 19. When you get these kinds of errors, you should start at the line it says and work backwards through your code to find the cause of the problem. One technique is just like you started to do: remove some code to see what happens. In this case, the error disappeared, so the next step is to put some of the code back in. For example, you could just add an empty function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<span id="demo"></span>
<span>-</span>
<span id="demo2"></span>
<script>
var words = ["Word", "Another Word", "One last word"];
var wordsLast = ["Suffix", "more", "and more"]
function textMasher() = {
}

</script>
<button type = "button" onclick =  textMasher()>sample text</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In this case, the error will come back, so you know the problem is with the two lines

```
function textMasher() = {
}
```

From there you can review the syntax for a function declaration and hopefully find the problem.